# Applying a filter to get a single item and using the filter function to transform the result

Tags: f#

In the following example code, I filter a list of strings on a regular expression, knowing that there can only be a single entry that will match that string. I then use the same match string to get 2 grouped values out of the single remaining value.

```
let input = ["aaaa bbbb";"aaabbbb";"cccc$$$$";"dddddda";" "] 

let ValuesOfAB (input: string list) = 
    let matchString = "(?<a>\w+)\s(?<b>\w+)"

    let value = input |> List.filter (fun line -> Regex.Matches(line, matchString).Count <> 0) 
                      |> List.head
    (Regex.Matches(value, matchString).[0].Groups.["a"].Value, Regex.Matches(value, matchString).[0].Groups.["b"].Value)

let a = ValuesOfAB input
```

Is there a better way where I don't have to use Regex.Matches on the same string again for a second time to get the values I wish to return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [List.pick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370236.aspx):

```
let input = ["aaaa bbbb";"aaabbbb";"cccc$$$$";"dddddda";" "] 

let valuesOfAB (input: string list) = 
    let matchString = "(?<a>\w+)\s(?<b>\w+)"
    let v = input |> List.pick (fun line -> let m = Regex.Match(line, matchString)
                                            if m.Success then Some m else None)
    v.Groups.["a"].Value, v.Groups.["b"].Value

let a = valuesOfAB input
```

*Explanation:*

You would like to match the first string in the list and return [Match](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.aspx) object in order that you don't have to run Regex again. `List.pick` fits the task quite well.

With each string, you need to match at least once so `Regex.Match` and `Match.Success` is enough for the purpose.